# How do I prevent a GtkAspectFrame from wasting space?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

```
<interface>
 <object class='GtkWindow' id='window'>
  <child>
   <object class='GtkBox' id='box'>
    <property name='orientation'>horizontal</property>
    <child>
     <object class='GtkAspectFrame' id='aspect_frame'>
      <property name='xalign'>0.0</property>
      <property name='yalign'>0.0</property>
      <child>
       <object class='GtkDrawingArea' id='drawing_area_A'>
        <property name='expand'>TRUE</property>
       </object>
      </child>
     </object>
    </child>
    <child>
     <!-- widget B goes here -->
    </child>
   </object>
  </child>
 </object>
</interface>
```

The above [GtkBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer#GtkBuilder) UI definition creates a square DrawingArea *A*. I want it to be as large as possible within its window, so I set the `expand` property of *A* to `TRUE`. However, when the window itself has a greater width than height, I want a widget, *B*, to fill the remainder width not used by the drawing area. Basically, I want this:

```
+--------------------+
|+-----------++-----+|
||           ||     ||
||     A     ||  B  ||
||           ||     ||
||           ||     ||
|+-----------++-----+|
+--------------------+
```

But I get this instead (if *B* has `expand` set to `FALSE`):

```
+--------------------+
|+-----------+    +-+|
||           |    | ||
||     A     |    |B||
||           |    | ||
||           |    | ||
|+-----------+    +-+|
+--------------------+
```

Or this (if *B* has `expand` set to `TRUE`):

```
+--------------------+
|+-------++---------+|
||       ||         ||
||   A   ||    B    ||
||       ||         ||
|+-------+|         ||
|         +---------+|
+--------------------+
```

How do I get GTK to cooperate?

Comment: I don't know GTK+ 3 or GtkBuilder, but you should probably dig in the direction of `gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height()`.  No idea if this is doable from XML or if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe A should be expand=true, fill=true, and B should be expand=false and fill=true.